# express, mocha testing always returns 404

Tags: javascript, express, mocha.js

My express POST route is:

```js
app.post("/addPost", function(req, res) {
  let newComment = { post: req.body.createP, comment: req.body.createC };
  myDB.push(newComment);
  res.render("index.ejs", { posts: myDB });
});
```

And my mocha test

```js
describe("POST /", function() {
  it("it ", function(done) {
    supertest(myApp.app)
      .post("/")
      .expect(200)
      .end(function(err, res) {
        if (err) return done(err);
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

Manually, the POST route works fine, but the mocha test always returns 404 instead of 200. Also, the mocha test for GET routes does work. Any ideas whats causing this?
Plus, how would one test html form data  being sent via a POST request. Thanks in advance!

Comment: your mocha test is attempting to post to '/'

Comment: cheers, for pointing that out

Comment: did that fix it?

Comment: yes, it worked, thanks

Comment: Great! I hope you don't mind but I will suggest this question be closed as it is very specific to how you had written your mocha test. If you wanted to get an answer to the last part of your question then please open it as a new question but make sure you have covered the [stackoverflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help the community provide the best answer.

Comment: OK, thanks your input, I'll do that

Comment: I need at least 250 reputation to close my question, so cannot do that yet, but cheers for linking the stackoverflow guidelines

Comment: No worries - I have flagged it for closing.